# creating unique new column id by selecting first 7 characters from a column and concatenating a number ie 1 to it in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column like the sample below:

**Column X** contains the following values:
 ty568gdrg,
 ed534hfkj,
 uh987cdfk,
 ij003lLKR

I need to create a new column Y which contains the first 7characters from column X concatenated to a number such as 4

ie

**Column Y**
 would contain the following new values: ty568gd4,
 ed534hf4,
 uh987cd4,
 ij003lL4

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**CONCAT()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) and [**LEFT()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) to accomplish this ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbb57/1/0)):

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(ColumnX, 7), '4') AS NewColumnID
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Substring() and Concat() to achieve this

```
 select columnA, concat(substring(columnA,1,7),'4') as columnB from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Linger has a great answer. If you also want the last number to be randomized instead of hard coding the 4 you could set a random number generator appended to the left function such as:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(ColumnX, 7), ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10) AS ColumnY
FROM Table
```